# NLTK - About managing tagset

Tags: python, nltk

There several tools for adding pos tags to words.But are we able to manage these tagset ? For example sometimes uncapitalized words can have /NNP tags. To avoid this should i add specific words to make them stay untagged or tell nltk to stop tagging uncapitalized word ?

**EDIT :**
The reason created this question is in my previous work i tried to grouping capitalized words which are supposed to be proper nouns(if it's a not starting word of sentence). But some time there is a word between words which are capitalized:

```
['Aynı, 'zamanda', 'Ayhan', 'Eczanesi']
```

Comment: Supervised POS taggers don't really rely on regexes. They're trained on annotated data, so in that sense the upper/lower case don't really matter as long as the trained model is robust enough, take a look at http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Comment: undestand that. tried a lot of example and it will always has the nnp tag. without editing that data are we able to control to tagging with statements ?